# Flask mongoengine connect through uri

Tags: mongodb, heroku, flask, mongoengine

I have a small flask application which I am deploying to Heroku.

My local configuration looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.mongoengine import MongoEngine

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.config["MONGODB_SETTINGS"] = {'DB': "my_app"}
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "secretpassword"

db = MongoEngine(app)
```

So, I know that I need to configure the app to use the Mongo `URI` method of connection, and I have my connection info:

```
mongodb://<user>:<password>@alex.mongohq.com:10043/app12345678
```

I am just a little stuck as to the syntax for modifying my app to connect through the `URI`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I got it working (finally):

```
from flask import Flask
from mongoengine import connect

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["MONGODB_DB"] = 'app12345678'
connect(
    'app12345678',
    username='heroku',
    password='a614e68b445d0d9d1c375740781073b4',
    host='mongodb://<user>:<password>@alex.mongohq.com:10043/app12345678',
    port=10043
)
```

Though I anticipate that various other configurations will work.

Comment: Where did username and password come from?

Comment: username/password comes from your mongohq account:  
create a free sandbox account, and in Databases->Admin->User create a username/password for the db. Then under Databases->Collections click 'Connect directly to your database', and try the mongo command first. Then copy the user/pass and app info to the solution posted here.

Comment: If you're still interested in getting the MongoEngine wrapper class to work, see my answer to your post :)

Answer (score 7):

When you look at the [flask-mongoengine code](https://github.com/sbook/flask-mongoengine/blob/master/flaskext/mongoengine/__init__.py#L34-L40), you can see what configuration variables are available

So this should work:

```
app.config["MONGODB_HOST"] = 'alex.mongohq.com/app12345678'
app.config["MONGODB_PORT"] = 10043
app.config["MONGODB_DATABASE"] = 'dbname'
app.config["MONGODB_USERNAME"] = 'user'
app.config["MONGODB_PASSWORD"] = 'password'
db = MongoEngine(app)
```

I'm not sure, if `app123` is the app or the database name. You might have to fiddle arround a little to get the connection. I had the same problem with Mongokit + MongoLab on Heroku :)

Also you could use the URI like this.

```
app.config["MONGODB_SETTINGS"] = {'DB': "my_app", "host":'mongodb://<user>:<password>@alex.mongohq.com:10043/app12345678'}
```

I have actually no idea, at what point "MONGODB_SETTINGS" is read, but it seemed to work, when I tried it in the shell.

Comment: I tried `app.config["MONGODB_SETTINGS"] = {"DB": 'app12345678', "host": 'mongodb://<user><password>@alex.mongohq.com:10043/app12345678` and various derivatives but still no connection. heroku gives me the `MONGOHQ_URL` variable, so surely this should be all I need?

Comment: Worked with URI as well

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to use the `flask.ext.mongoengine.MongoEngine` wrapper class to do this rather than `mongoengine.connect()`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.mongoengine import MongoEngine

app = Flask(__name__)

HOST = '<hostname>'  # ex: 'oceanic.mongohq.com'
db_settings = {
    'MONGODB_DB': '<database>',
    'MONGODB_USERNAME': '<username>',
    'MONGODB_PASSWORD': '<password>',
    'MONGODB_PORT': <port>,
}
app.config = dict(list(app.config.items()) + list(db_settings.items()))
app.config["MONGODB_HOST"] = ('mongodb://%(MONGODB_USERNAME)s:%(MONGODB_PASSWORD)s@'+
                               HOST +':%(MONGODB_PORT)s/%(MONGODB_DB)s') % db_settings

db = MongoEngine(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

If you're using mongohq, `app.config["MONGODB_HOST"]` should match the Mongo URI under Databases->Admin->Overview.

You can then follow **MongoDB**'s [tumblelog tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/write-a-tumblelog-application-with-flask-mongoengine/) using this setup to write your first app called **tumblelog**.

Using python's nifty object introspection (python oh how I *love* you so), you can see how the MongoEngine wrapper class accomplishes this:

```
from flask.ext.mongoengine import MongoEngine
import inspect
print(inspect.getsource(MongoEngine))
    ...
    conn_settings = {
        'db': app.config.get('MONGODB_DB', None),
        'username': app.config.get('MONGODB_USERNAME', None),
        'password': app.config.get('MONGODB_PASSWORD', None),
        'host': app.config.get('MONGODB_HOST', None),
        'port': int(app.config.get('MONGODB_PORT', 0)) or None
    }
     ...
     self.connection = mongoengine.connect(**conn_settings)
     ...
     self.app = app
```