# flask-mongoengine with ssl cert

Tags: python, mongodb, ssl, flask, flask-mongoengine

I am building a flask app that will store data in MongoDB. For this I am using `Flask-Mongoengine`, now my problem is that I need to use a `ssl_ca_cert` and `SSL=true` for connecting to MongoDB. I am not able to find any documentation which says anything about this. I know with `PyMongo` we can use these options but I want to use it with Flask-Mongoengine. Is there any way I can do that? Any `app.config[]` parameter to set the `ssl_ca_cert` and `ssl=True`? Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT:**

Something is mentioned [here](https://github.com/MongoEngine/flask-mongoengine/issues/247) about these options but I am not able to figure out how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use the URI string connection for this, i.e the `MONGODB_HOST` config parameter (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666968/flask-mongoengine-connect-through-uri) for an example).

Something like:

```
app.config["MONGODB_HOST"] = "mongodb://user:password@hostname:port/db_name?ssl=true&ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_REQUIRED&ssl_ca_certs={your_cert_path}"
```

Comment: Is it working in this way?